# Spring AOP not triggering on bean in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-aop

I'm trying to get an aspect to trigger and do something before one of the beans in my spring integration service is called.  Here's my code so far..

**global-context.xml**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
...
<bean class="com.ryanstull.spring.integration.DebugAdvice"/>
```

Here's my bean in my spring integration pipeline

```
package com.ryanstull.spring.integration;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;

public class DebugTransformer{

    @Transformer
    public Object transformPayload(Object arg0) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("In debug transformer");
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

My aspect

```
@Aspect
public class DebugAdvice{

    public DebugAdvice(){
    }

    @Before("within(com.ryanstull.spring.integration..*) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public void tester(){
        System.out.println("Before Debug Transformer advice.");
    }
}
```

Yet for some reason whenever I run my application I only ever see "In debug transformer" and it seems like my advice is never triggered.

Also, I'm working on a legacy application that is using spring 3.2.3 and spring integration 2.2.4

Comment: Just check your spring configuration file , not sure but i think you have not configured DebugTransformer class

Comment: How else do you have to configure it other than declaring the bean?

Comment: In your global-context.xml file you have only added DebugAdvice bean as you have posted but not DebugTransformer . May be you missed it

Comment: Oh that's declared in my spring integration service file

Answer (score 0):

Interesting; it works if the transformer is a POJO (i.e. remove `extends AbstractPayloadTransformer<Object,Object>`).

We generally recommend using POJOs but if you want to extend `AbstractPayloadTransformer`, then...

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

...works.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Gary! I update my code so the Transformer is annotation based now, but unfortunately it still isn't working.  Something I forgot to mention in my original question is that this is a legacy application and is running on spring 3.2.3 and spring integration 2.2.4, so that might be affecting the result

Comment: I just tested with those versions and got the same result - works with a POJO transformer or with `proxy-target-class`. I pushed it to [my sandbox here](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so35801772).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it's still not working. Another thing I didn't mention is that my project is offline so I'm not sure if there would be a problem resolving the "<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>" tag.  If that's not an issue though, I guess it must be something else in my project configuration.

Comment: Shouldn't be - Spring resolves the XML schema from the jar. Maybe DEBUG logging will help.

Comment: If I try to use "proxy-target-class="true" my application fails to boot and I get a bunch of errors about not being able to generate subclasses of certain classes.  I'm guessing this is because spring AOP is using proxying to implement the aspects.

The thing I don't get though is why proxt-target-class="true" makes some unrelated class affect by the aspects.

Is there some way to get the functionality provided by proxt-target-class="true" but make it only target the one class I need?

Comment: I really don't know; sorry; I just noticed that with a POJO transformer, we get a CGLIB proxy, with the subsclass, we get a JDK proxy; I realize you can't change the proxy method for the other classes, so we need to figure out why the POJO transformer doesn't work for you. If you can post a sample app like mine, I'll take a look.